# python Argumentparser. executable file and source-code file as arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't figure out how to pass arguments from the command line properly. I want to pass an executable program and a source code file as arguments. It seems to be working well until I try to open the source code file. What am I doing wrong?

Command line:

```
$ my_script.py  my_executable  source_code.fe
```

Code:

```
import sys, argparse 
def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Description of program')

    parser.add_argument('exe', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
    parser.add_argument('src_file', type=argparse.FileType('r'))

    #args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    args = parser.parse_args()

    infile = open(args.src_file)
    #child = subprocess.run( [exe], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=infile)

   if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Comment: What does it tell you you're doing wrong? Is there an error? Give a [mcve]; what you've posted doesn't seem to be valid syntactically.

Comment: If you are using `FileType`, both `args.exe` and `args.src_file` are already open file handles, not just file names.

Comment: I think `argparse.FileType` opens the file for you; calling `open` yourself is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileType` essentially produces a wrapper around `open`. The attribute in the value returned by `parse_args` *is* a file-like object already.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Description of program')

parser.add_argument('exe', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('src_file', type=argparse.FileType('r'))

args = parser.parse_args()

infile = args.src_file
```

---

At its simplest, you could define `FileType` yourself as

```
def FileType(*args, **kwargs):
    def _(fname):
        return open(fname, *args, **kwargs)
    return _
```

The [real definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/argparse.py#L1178) handles `-` as an alias for standard input or standard output as appropriate for the given mode, as well as better error handling.